# php shopping cart session id remove

Tags: php, session

if have session cart items more than 1 its not work.. but its have only one its work. what happen for this

I put my all of codes in session. check what happen for this case...

here is my php code for this link `?action=remove&id=<value>`

```
function checkCartForItem($addItem, $cartItems) {
     if (is_array($cartItems)){
          foreach($cartItems as $key => $item) {
              if($item['id'] === $addItem)
                  return $key;
          }
     }
     return false;
}

if (!empty($_GET['qty'])) {

    $qty = $_GET['qty'];
}

//Store it in a Array
$ITEM = array(
//Item name     
'id' => $_POST['id']    

);

$addItem = $_GET['id'];


//check
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_GET["qty"])) {

            $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id='" . $_GET["id"] . "'");
            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["id"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["product_name"], 'id'=>$productByCode[0]["id"], 'quantity'=>$qty, 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["new_price"]));

            $itemExists = checkCartForItem($addItem, $_SESSION['cart_item']); 

            if ($itemExists !== false){  
                $_SESSION['cart_item'][$itemExists]['quantity'] = $qty ; 
            } else { 

                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {

                    if(in_array($productByCode[0]["id"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                                if($productByCode[0]["id"] == $k)
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $qty;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                }   
            } 
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["id"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);      
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }

    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;  
}
}
```

array (`print_r($_SESSION["cart_item"]);`)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Sadfsafsadf [id] => 11 [quantity] => 1 [price] => safsafsa ) [1] => Array ( [name] => TP-LINK 4 Port Wireless Dual Band N600 [id] => 13 [quantity] => 1 [price] => 15980 ) )
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that all items are added to the cart successfully? $_SESSION['cart_item'] is an array, and contains the items you want? You say it doesn't work -- do you mean that the item is not removed, or that everything is removed? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: @user3501407 can you share your $_SESSION["cart_item"] array.

Comment: @user3501407 please print your array like `print_r($_SESSION["cart_item"]);` and copy+paste the results here, i want to see the structure of your array

Comment: @LuthandoLoot i updated print_r cart item plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake on this line. if($_GET["id"] == [$k])

```
 case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["id"] == $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]['id'])
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);      
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }

    break;
```

Comment: plzz give me a full code for this one.. i havent idea about this

Comment: plzz help me for this.. i cant fix it

Comment: @user3501407 can you post your array $_SESSION["cart_item"] and the value of $_GET[id]

Comment: @user3501407. I have updated my answer. can you review it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if($_GET["id"] == $k)
```

do this

```
if($_GET["id"] == $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 case "remove":
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
               if($_GET["id"] == $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]['id'])// 
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);      
                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
        }
    }
```

it works!!